# scroll on three finger swipe for ios

Tags: javascript, ios, css, scrollbar

I need to make scroll on three finger touch and swipe, so I'm doing `overflow: scroll;` and `width` and `height` are ok too, I even tried `white-space: nowrap;` `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` but no result, it works fine on Android browsers, but not on IOS